# Stanford CoreNLP POS tagging in French

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech, french

I am looking for a way to use Pos tagging for French sentences with Python. I saw that we could use Stanford CoreNLP but after several searches on google, I did not find real examples that could satisfy me ..
It would be great to have a piece of code that shows me how to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous Python wrappers for Stanford CoreNLP. There is a list [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/other-languages.html) (along with wrappers for other languages). You need to run the [Stanford CoreNLP server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) first. Here is a bit of code that uses [pycorenlp](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp):

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')

text = "Ceci est un test de l'étiqueteur morpho-syntaxique du français."

output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
  'annotators': 'tokenize, ssplit, pos',
  'outputFormat': 'json'
  })

from pprint import pprint
pprint(output)
```

The result is a JSON data structure (you can choose other formats by specifying a different value, for the `outputFormat` property e.g. 'text', 'xml'...) with all the annotations, including POS tags (the `pos` attribute for each token), as follows:

```
{'sentences': [{'index': 0,
                'tokens': [{'after': ' ',
                            'before': '',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 0,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 4,
                            'index': 1,
                            'originalText': 'Ceci',
                            'pos': 'NNP',
                            'word': 'Ceci'},
                           {'after': ' ',
                            'before': ' ',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 5,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 8,
                            'index': 2,
                            'originalText': 'est',
                            'pos': 'NNP',
                            'word': 'est'},
                           {'after': ' ',
                            'before': ' ',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 9,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 11,
                            'index': 3,
                            'originalText': 'un',
                            'pos': 'JJ',
                            'word': 'un'},
                           {'after': ' ',
                            'before': ' ',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 12,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 16,
                            'index': 4,
                            'originalText': 'test',
                            'pos': 'NN',
                            'word': 'test'},
                           {'after': ' ',
                            'before': ' ',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 17,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 19,
                            'index': 5,
                            'originalText': 'de',
                            'pos': 'IN',
                            'word': 'de'},
                           {'after': ' ',
                            'before': ' ',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 20,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 32,
                            'index': 6,
                            'originalText': "l'étiqueteur",
                            'pos': 'JJ',
                            'word': "l'étiqueteur"},
                           {'after': ' ',
                            'before': ' ',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 33,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 50,
                            'index': 7,
                            'originalText': 'morpho-syntaxique',
                            'pos': 'JJ',
                            'word': 'morpho-syntaxique'},
                           {'after': ' ',
                            'before': ' ',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 51,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 53,
                            'index': 8,
                            'originalText': 'du',
                            'pos': 'NNP',
                            'word': 'du'},
                           {'after': '',
                            'before': ' ',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 54,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 62,
                            'index': 9,
                            'originalText': 'français',
                            'pos': 'NN',
                            'word': 'français'},
                           {'after': '',
                            'before': '',
                            'characterOffsetBegin': 62,
                            'characterOffsetEnd': 63,
                            'index': 10,
                            'originalText': '.',
                            'pos': '.',
                            'word': '.'}]}]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems that I can not connect to locaslhost 9000. I get the error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Did you download Stanford CoreNLP and run the server first (see the link in my post)? If you don't do this before running the script then you will get an error.